# Error performing request (loadMoreOutputTail): /execution/tailExecutionOutput?format=json in rundeck

Tags: java, war, rundeck

[image]

Why can not view log output in rundeck? it show above  error

Comment: Could you elaborate? Can you share an example job definition to test?

Comment: Also, which rundeck version are you using? Any clue on service.log file? ( at /var/log/rundeck path)

Comment: actually we used  2.8.1

Answer (score 2):

I have restarted rundeck. After that, it works properly.
for more  details  https://github.com/rundeck/rundeck/issues/2667

Answer (score 1):

That's a known [issue](https://github.com/rundeck/rundeck/issues/2667) fixed [here](https://github.com/rundeck/rundeck/commit/35bf9ff4fea703ea54e3445bd8cae7d66e25b9b0) (as you say in your answer). Upgrading your Rundeck instance to the latest version is a good way to avoid that. The gap between the 2.8.X branch and 3.3.X is so big. So, the best way to upgrade is to exporting your projects/keys/data and import it later on a fresh 3.3.X Rundeck instance. Take a look at [this](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/administration/maintenance/backup.html#backup-and-recovery).